# c++ string constructor under the hood

Tags: c++

I have a simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

string read0() {
    int length = 4;

    char *cstr = new char[length];

    string str(cstr);

    delete[] cstr;

    return str;
}

string read1() {
    int length = 4;

    char cstr[length];

    memset(cstr, '-', 4);

    string str(cstr);

   return str;
}

string read2() {
    const char* cstr = "abcd";

    string str(cstr);

    return str;
}
```

In all 3 functions above, for constructing a string, they `call basic_string( const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()`. When I use valgrind/massif to check the heap usage, function read0 only uses 4 bytes (from `new`), but read1 and read2 both use 29 bytes.

Here's some detail output of massif:

For read0:

> 16.67% (4B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
>
> ->16.67% (4B) 0x400A0B: read0() (main.cpp:10)
>
> ->16.67% (4B) 0x400BC8: main (main.cpp:40)

For read1 and read2:

> 72.50% (29B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
>
> ->72.50% (29B) 0x4EE93B7: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator const&) (in
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
>
> ->72.50% (29B) 0x4EEAD93: char* std::string::_S_construct(char const*, char const*, std::allocator const&,
>   std::forward_iterator_tag) (in
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
>
> ->72.50% (29B) 0x4EEAE71: std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(char
>   const*, std::allocator const&) (in
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17)
>
> ->72.50% (29B) 0x400B81: read2() (main.cpp:34)
>
> ->72.50% (29B) 0x400BC8: main (main.cpp:40)

What causes this difference?

Comment: You should null terminate those C strings.

Comment: @Peter: Yup, just realize that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think I know why this is.

In `read0`, you do:

```
char *cstr = new char[length];
string str(cstr);
```

You don't initialize `cstr` at all, so it could be undefined. The string constructor takes a **null-terminated** c-string and copies it up [until the null terminator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/). I think it finds it at the very first element, so it's only copying the pointer that would point to such a string, which presumably takes up 4 bytes.

I think your `read1` is similar. It ends up finding a null terminator at the some point past the string itself, since it's not null-terminated, which ends up being 29 bytes.

I don't know why `read2` is doing the same thing though, to be honest. It could be I'm wrong about the reason for `read1` above and that 29 bytes (minus the 4 characters/bytes in the c-string) is the minimal operating cost of a string in your architecture and compiler's implementation of the STL.

**In any case**, to narrow down the various possibilities, I suggest you null-terminate the strings in `read0` and `read1` and try your experiment again by allocating one extra element and setting the last element to `'\0'` or by using the alternative string constructor that takes an additional second parameter which denotes how many characters to copy:

```
string(non_null_terminated_string, this_many_characters_to_copy)
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge. you are right. In read0, string(cstr) never actually allocates memory until I put a memset on cstr. And both read1 and read2 allocate for string(), so they have 29 bytes memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

In read0 you are initializing str from cstr which is empty (zero length).  In read1 and read2 you are initializing str from non-empty strings.  The amount of heap actually allocated in the latter cases (29 bytes) is larger than strictly necessary to make heap management faster and simpler - for example it's not unusual to allocate heap in chunks of 32 bytes (or some other rounded number).

Also, your read1 is bugged: if you want cstr to contain "----" then you need cstr[5], not cstr[4].  Your array needs space for the string-terminating zero.  And then you should probably use strcpy(cstr, "----") rather that memset(cstr, '-', 4) otherwise cstr will not have the (needed) zero terminator.